# Unable to get the package mwavepy to work correctly

Tags: python

I have just installed mwavepy and pyvisa and when i go to import these packages i get the error

```
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\mwavepy\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    import media
ImportError: No module named 'media'
```

I've tried import media and it doesn't work, additionally i went into the **init**.py file and commented out media and it just moved onto the next import calibration and gave the same error.

Any suggestions or tip would be great. I'm using python 3.5

Comment: Are You sure, that You've installed all req. packages at beginning ? 
[req_here!](https://pythonhosted.org/mwavepy/tutorials/installation.html#requirements)

Comment: Figured it out, package works fine with 2.7 but not with 3.5